# Search a string in a elasticsearch query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm strugling with Elasticsearch trying to find a way of getting the frame number on which certain string appears.
Having this json result I would Like to get the frame_number value where text contains the string "esstre" which is the last line youll see, so the result would be 0, from frame_number 0.

I have tried this way but doesn't works at all:

```
search_param = {
     'query': {
         'match': {
             'frames.text': '*'+string+'*'
             # 'frames':{
             #     'text': '*'+string+'*'
             #     } 
         }
 }
 }

resp = _es.get(index="siv_data",  body=search_param)
print(resp)
```

```js
{
  "platform": "youtube",
  "name_link": "XcljQpU6dc4",
  "total_frames": 1,
  "frames": [
    {
      "frame_number": 0,
      "text": [
        " ",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "Deu eae a Cea key",
        "",
        "File Edit",
        "",
        "a EXPLORER",
        "",
        "V OPEN EDITORS",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "OCU",
        "",
        "! client yaml helm/dev/hel...",
        "® elasticsearch_o... 1,M",
        "X & main.py app/ima... 2,M",
        "Settings",
        "® scaleway_object_storag...",
        "",
        "V STRING-IN-VIDEO",
        "£ DuILd-dockerymt",
        "",
        "! update-version.yml",
        "V app °",
        "> api e",
        "~ downloaders",
        "® Dockerfile",
        "® main.py",
        "@ README.md",
        "requirements.txt",
        "> Front",
        " image_reading e",
        "> _pycache_",
        "> env",
        "© session",
        "> _pycache_",
        "® config.py",
        "config.py.tmpl",
        "© Dockerfile",
        "| ® elasticsearch_oper... 1,M",
        "® main.py 2M",
        "® postgresql_operator.py",
        "requirements.txt",
        "® scaleway_object_storage.py",
        "\\ video_parser",
        "> env",
        "® Dockerfile",
        "® main.py",
        "",
        "  ",
        "",
        "> OUTLINI",
        "> TIMELINE",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "ECCS nO. mee",
        "",
        "! client.yamt",
        "",
        "® elasticsearch_operator.py 1,M ® main.py 2,M x Settings",
        "",
        "app > image_reading > @ main.py >..",
        "",
        "insert_elasticsearch_data(json_head)",
        "# return json_head",
        "",
        "#Given the json from the return of build_json, insert it into the elasticsearch",
        "# def insert_in_elasticsearch(json_head):",
        "# print(\"Inserting in elasticsearch\")",
        "# insert_elasticsearch_data(json_head)",
        "",
        "def insert_in_database(key, s3_url):",
        "register = register_buid(key, s3_url)",
        "insert_register(register)",
        "",
        "def register_buid(key, s3_url):",
        "register = {}",
        "register['key'] = key",
        "register['s3_url'] = s3_url",
        "return register",
        "",
        "def test_elasticsearch():",
        "connect_elasticsearch()",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "if __name_",
        "try:",
        "# get_all_frames()",
        "# get_frames_per_second(video_long)",
        "# read_frame(\"759\")",
        "# build_json(platform_name, name_link, 2)",
        "build_json(platform_name, name_link, get_total_frames())",
        "# create database()",
        "# insert_in_database(\"hi2\", \"dssdsd\")",
        "# read_image()",
        "# test_elasticsearch()",
        "# read_elasticsearch()",
        "except KeyboardInterrupt:",
        "print('Interrupted')",
        "try:",
        "sys.exit(0)",
        "except SystemExit:",
        "os. _exit(0)",
        "",
        "J__main_':",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "® scaleway_object_storage.py",
        "",
        "> write_object",
        "",
        "ri",
        "",
        "Oia)",
        "",
        "Aa ab, a 20F1",
        "",
        "LF",
        "",
        "rare",
        "",
        "esstre"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
    search_param = {
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "frames.text", "query" : "*"+string+"*"}
} }

_es = connect_elasticsearch()

# resp = _es.search(index="siv_data",  body=search_param, filter_path=['hits.hits'])
resp = _es.search(index="siv_data",  body=search_param)
print(resp)
print("-------------------------------")
print(resp['hits']['hits'][0]["_source"]["frames"][0]["frame_number"])
```